# How can I assign a cell's comments to another cell in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Within google sheets (not API) is there a way to assign a cell's comment to another cell in a formula?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there is a formula to access a cell's comments. You could write a custom function with Apps Script though, using the `setNote()` method.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotenote

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions?hl=en